# Anomalous magnetic dipole moment of muon

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, quantum-anomalies

I'm currently studying for my oral exams and came across exercise 17.1 in Schwartz's Introduction to Quantum Field Theory. In the exercise, we consider the following Lagrangian for super symmetry:
$$\mathcal{L}_{SUSY} = \mathcal{L}_{SM}+(\partial_\mu \widetilde{e}+igA_\mu\widetilde{e})(\partial_\mu \widetilde{e}^*-igA_\mu \widetilde{e}^*)+m_{\widetilde{e}}^2\widetilde{e}^2+g\widetilde{e}\overline{e}\widetilde{A}+\overline{\widetilde{A}}(\gamma^\rho{\partial_\rho}+m_{\widetilde{A}})\widetilde{A}$$
$$+(\partial_\mu \widetilde{\mu}+igA_\mu \widetilde{\mu})(\partial_\mu \widetilde{\mu}^*-igA_\mu \widetilde{\mu}^*)+m_{\widetilde{\mu}}^2\widetilde{\mu}^2+g\widetilde{\mu}\overline{\mu}\widetilde{A}$$
where $\tilde{A}$ is the photino and $\tilde{\mu}$ is smuon. I am interested in computing  the contribution of loops involving the smuon to the muon's magnetic dipole moment. Schwartz outlines a nice way to approach this in Chapter 17 and a solution [here](https://polozov.cf/files/problem17-1.pdf) that follows Schwartz's method. However, in this linked solution, they have the following:
$$i\mathcal{M}_2^\mu = (-ig)^3 \int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{i(\gamma^\rho k_\rho - \gamma^\alpha q^1_\alpha+m_{\tilde{A}})}{(k-q_1)^2-m_{\tilde{A}}^2+i\epsilon}\overline{u}(q_2)\frac{i(k^\mu +(k^\mu +p^\mu))}{(p+k)^2-m_{\tilde{\mu}}^2+i\epsilon}\frac{i}{k^2-m_{\tilde{\mu}}^2+i\epsilon}u(q_1)$$
corresponding to the diagram

[image]

What set of Feynman rules led them to this result? I ask because they appear to be very different than the ones used for QED described in Schwartz. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think you should trust random PDFs on the internet -- it would usually be faster and more reliable to work things out for yourself. I already see a mistake in the expression you wrote and there are probably more.

Comment: Anyway, for the Feynman rules, have you heard of "scalar QED"? It's covered earlier in Schwartz.

Comment: Yes, I have heard of the Feynman rules for scalar QED. Is that what were supposed to be using to determine $\mathcal{M}_2^{\mu\mu}$ here? Why wouldn't we use the Feynman rules for spinor QED?

Comment: Because the smuon is a scalar, as you can see from the Lagrangian.

Comment: I see. So what should the propagator be for the photino? It doesn't seem like we can use the same propagator as that for the photon since we are assuming that the photino has mass.

Comment: I suppose I use the Feynman rule for a spinor propagator?

Comment: You are being confused by the name “photino” just like you were confused by the name “smuon”. A smuon isn’t anything like a muon and a photino isn’t anything like a photon. If you look at the kinetic term for the photino, it is that of a Dirac spinor.

Comment: *Is that what were supposed to be using to determine $\mathcal M^{\mu\mu}_2$ here?* The amplitude $\mathcal M^\mu_2$ has only one Lorentz index.

Comment: Aren't the Feynman rules evident in the action you started from?